# Old Visual Basic 5 app with SendKeys gives Permission denied on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1

I have an old program I made several years ago, compiled in Native Code, in Visual Basic 5. I lost the original source code in some old Hard Disk...

It uses a

```
SendKeys ("{LEFT}")
```

Then I get this error:

```
Run-time error '70':
Permission denied
```

I already disabled UAC, as I did on windows 7 (and worked), but it did not work in windows 8.1 Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: I hope you have tried running as administrator

Comment: Yes, I tried that. I set UAC to lowest setting. I also set it to run on Windows XP compatibility mode. On Windows 7 it worked with these settings. On windows 8.1 the Run-time error '70': Permission denied  persisted.

Comment: Setting the compatibility mode might work: http://visualbasicnetcode.blogspot.co.uk/p/visual-basic-60-gets-run-time-error-70.html

Comment: moving the slider down **NO LONGER DISABLES UAC** in Windows 8.x

Comment: Is there some registry change to disable UAC in Windows 8.1?

Comment: same as in Vista/7. Set the value EnableLUA in the registry (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System) to 0. But this disabled the new store apps.

Comment: Do you have the last VB5 runtime installed?

Answer (score 2):

Paste this inside Project - Add Module - Open

```
Public Sub Sendkeys(text$, Optional wait As Boolean = False)
   Dim WshShell As Object
   Set WshShell = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
   WshShell.Sendkeys text, wait
   Set WshShell = Nothing
End Sub
```

You will never face that problem again.